# Cleanest way to get list of Django objects that have same foreign key and display them in a view

Tags: python, django

I am a beginner in Django and would like some advice regarding best practices.

I have the following model:

```
class Company(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

class Interview(models.Model):
    company = models.ForeignKey(Company, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    position = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

(I didn't include the `__str__` methods for conciseness)

I have the following path:
`path('<int:company_id>/', views.detail, name='detail')`

Where I want the company to be displayed (let's say its `company_id=1`, along with all the `interview` objects that have `company=1`). So the view should look something like:

[image: company_detail_view]

Here is my view method:

```
def detail(request, company_id):
    company = get_object_or_404(Company, pk=company_id)
    return render(request, 'core/detail.html', {'company': company, 'interviews': Interview.objects.filter(company_id=company_id)})
```

And my `detail.html` file:

```
<h1>{{ company }}</h1>
<ul>
{% for interview in interviews %}
    <li>{{ interview.position }}</li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Which works. However, I am not sure if passing the interviews `QuerySet` like that is a good practice or not. Is there a way to pass only the `company` object and get the interviews from that? In general, is there a better way to get a list of objects that have the same foreign key? In this case for example, would it be possible to instead of doing:

```
Interview.objects.filter(company_id=company_id)
```

Doing:

```
company.interviews
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> However, I am not sure if passing the interviews QuerySet like that is a good practice or not.

This is good practice, known as [dependency injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection). If someone asks for your business card, you wouldn't give them your wallet and let them fish it out - you can think of passing objects to the template renderer the same way. Passing only the `company` object would mean there would have to be more logic in your `detail.html` template to fish out the `interviews`, which is less than ideal. The way you currently do it serves as documentation as to what objects are required by the `detail.html` template.

> In general, is there a better way to get a list of objects that have the same foreign key?

You can specify a [`related_name`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name) for the `company` foreign key on your `Interview` model like so.

```
class Company(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

class Interview(models.Model):
    company = models.ForeignKey(Company, related_name='interviews', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    position = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

Then you can access all interviews for a company like `company.interviews.all()`